# Setting border size on button on mouse over in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to set the border colour property on a button when user hovers on it. Currently I am using following XAML.

```
                                <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0081a7"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFffffff"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ccCCCCCC"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gold"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
```

This works fine only for colour changes. Border on the other hand is not displayed at all. I am sure, I am missing something very simple, only thing is I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually utilising the `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` properties... you need to actually do something with them from *inside* your `ControlTemplate`. Try this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding 
        BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something dumb.